# How do I calculate the proportion of occupation in a 3D array in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I have some large data files of x,y,z coordinates of fish in a net pen. I have already calculated the proportion of the pen covered in the x,y plane with a little help from some kind people on stackoverflow:

```
prop.coverage <- function(xmin7 = 8, xmax7 = 33, ymin7 = 11.5, ymax7 = 36.5,      xmin8 = 35, xmax8 = 60, ymin8 = 11.5, ymax8 = 36.5, boxsize = 0.3) {
 fish.id <- subset(dayfile, PEN == '7')
 x.grid <- floor((fish.id$PosX - xmin7) / boxsize) + 1
 y.grid <- floor((fish.id$PosY - ymin7) / boxsize) + 1
 x.grid.max <- floor((xmax7 - xmin7) / boxsize) + 1
 y.grid.max <- floor((ymax7 - ymin7) / boxsize) + 1
 t.x <- sort(unique(x.grid))
 t.y <- sort(unique(y.grid))
 tx.range <- c(min(which(t.x > 0)), max(which(t.x <= x.grid.max)))
 ty.range <- c(min(which(t.y > 0)), max(which(t.y <= y.grid.max)))
 t.xy <- table(y.grid, x.grid)[ty.range[1]:ty.range[2],tx.range[1]:tx.range[2]]
 grid.cov.xy <- matrix(0,nrow=y.grid.max,ncol=x.grid.max)
 t.x <- t.x[(t.x > 0) & (t.x <=x.grid.max)]
 t.y <- t.y[(t.y > 0) & (t.y <=y.grid.max)]
 eg.xy <- expand.grid(t.y,t.x)
 grid.cov.xy[cbind(eg.xy$Var1,eg.xy$Var2)] <- as.vector(t.xy)  
 coverage.P7 <- matrix(c(length(which(grid.cov.xy > 0)), length(grid.cov.xy),    length(which(grid.cov.xy > 0))/length(grid.cov.xy)), ncol = 3)
 colnames(coverage.P7) <- c('occupied', 'total', 'proportion')
}
```

I would now like to extend this to calculate the proportion of the pen covered in three dimensions. I'm guessing this will involve using a 3D array. I've added some code to create a second table of coverage in the y,z dimension.

```
z.grid <- floor((fish.id$PosZ - zmin7) / boxsize) + 1
z.grid.max <- floor((zmax7 - zmin7) / boxsize) + 1
t.z <- sort(unique(z.grid))
tz.range <- c(min(which(t.z > 0)), max(which(t.z <= z.grid.max)))
t.yz <- table(y.grid, z.grid)[ty.range[1]:ty.range[2],tz.range[1]:tz.range[2]]
grid.cov.yz <- matrix(0,nrow=y.grid.max,ncol=z.grid.max)
t.z <- t.z[(t.z > 0) & (t.z <= z.grid.max)]
eg.yz <- expand.grid(t.y,t.z)
grid.cov.yz[cbind(eg.yz$Var1,eg.yz$Var2)] <- as.vector(t.yz)
```

However, I'm not sure how to map my 2D tables of grid coverage into an array. Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

*edit*

This is what my data looks like (positions are in metres):

```
Fish ID EchoTime            PosX    PosY    PosZ
7017    16/06/2016 00:03:39 12.94   33.18   18.92
7017    16/06/2016 00:03:53 13.02   32.66   15.69
7017    16/06/2016 00:03:54 17.24   28.03   13.27
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:00 13.09   32.69   15.05
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:01 16.15   29.33   13.33
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:07 12.96   32.79   14.3
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:08 14.74   31.07   13.47
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:14 12.49   33.12   13.94
7017    16/06/2016 00:04:15 13.93   31.84   13.49
```

This is the output I want:

```
occupied total  proportion
5648     122586 0.046
```

Where 'total' is the number of cells in a 3D grid covering an volume of 25*25*25m, 'occupied' is the number of those cells occupied by a fish and 'proportion' is the proportion of the cells occupied.

Comment: Could you add a more reproducible example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz I've added an example now.